# set checkbox based on parameters in iWork Numbers

Tags: numbers, iwork

I would like to be able to tick or untick a checkbox in iWork Numbers based on certain parameters.

The spreadsheet is a list of projects (Column C), each composed of several tasks (column D). Column B is a completion date that gets filled in by the user when a task is completed. Column A contains checkboxes.

I would like to be able to automatically check the box in column A when a date is entered into column B. Further, I would like to automatically check the box for the project once all the boxes are checked for the encompassed tasks.

A sample code for task completion would be: IF(B2<>"",TRUE,FALSE).
Sample for project completion would be: IF(COUNTIF(C,C2)=COUNTIFS(C,C2,B,"<>"&""),TRUE,FALSE).

What I'm hoping to accomplish is to convert the TRUE or FALSE result of the formula into a ticked or unticked checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, cells formatted with as "Checkbox" type will not accept a formula in the current version of Numbers. (version 4.3 as of this posting)

One workaround is to use a formula such as this: `=IF(ISBLANK(DateCell),"","✓"` in the cell you wish to have the tick mark.  Of course, one can get much more creative than this, but it is a start.

The 'Check Mark', as it is called in the system can be found in the Character Viewer.

---

[image: Formula for checkmark]

[image: Live Demo]

[image: Character Viewer]